# Is there any method to move some source code from on folder to another easily in vs2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I'v write lots of code in c++ vs2005.
I decided to move some source code to other folder.
It make lots of compile errors, because of include error,

Is there a tool to move source code easily, which can modify .h include automaticly?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the new location of the files to the include path of your project:

> Project Properties->C/C++->Additional
>   Include Directories:

This will treat these files as if they were in the local folder of your project.